# Cronjob on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django App

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cron-task

Im having issue on running my cron jobs from Django EB.
When i deployed it shows no error but the cronjob is not running.
the import_incontact_statelogs.py is a script that should dump a set of data to my database.

Here's my config file inside .ebextension
-----Cronjob.config--------------

```
files:
    "/usr/local/bin/check_leader_only_instance.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            INSTANCE_ID=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>/dev/null`
            REGION=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document 2>/dev/null | jq -r .region`

            # Find the Auto Scaling Group name from the Elastic Beanstalk environment
            ASG=`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" \
                --region $REGION --output json | jq -r '.[][] | select(.Key=="aws:autoscaling:groupName") | .Value'`

            # Find the first instance in the Auto Scaling Group
            FIRST=`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $ASG \
                --region $REGION --output json | \
                jq -r '.AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[] | select(.LifecycleState=="InService") | .InstanceId' | sort | head -1`

            # If the instance ids are the same exit 0
            [ "$FIRST" = "$INSTANCE_ID" ]

    "/usr/local/bin/my_cron_script.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |            
            #!/bin/bash
            /usr/local/bin/check_leader_only_instance.sh || exit
            source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
            source /opt/python/current/env
            cd /opt/python/current/app
            python manage.py shell < automations/import_incontact_statelogs.py

    "/etc/cron.d/daily_cron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */10 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/my_cron_script.sh 

commands:
  rm_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: I wonder if you have to restart the cron service as well? I also recommend that you try running the cron manually (by SSHing to the instance), see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42715/130263.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this. I tried to execute the `my_cron_script.sh` manually via `eb ssh` and I got an error when the script tried to execute `check_leader_only_instance.sh`. The error is the following: `/usr/local/bin/check_leader_only_instance.sh: line 3: jq: command not found
`. This on line 3,6 and 9. Basically all the lines with command `jq`.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm about to try not executing the `check_leader_only_instance.sh`, but I know on production this could cause problems with duplicate cron executions...

Comment: still no go. still having issues on my cron in EB.

Comment: any news on this? I suddenly start having problems with cron again..